# TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: learning_rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to load a Keras model which was trained on an Azure VM (NC promo). But I am getting the following error.

> TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer:learning_rate

EDIT:

Here is the code snippet that I am using to load my model:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model_name.h5')
```

Comment: Please can you show your code?

Comment: @RobBricheno do you want to know the entire model architecture?

Comment: This seems to be a version problem.... I don't know now how to deal with h5 files, but they basically contain some keys and information. You may need to open this file and replace `learning_rate` with `lr`.

Comment: @DanielMöller how to open an h5 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by reinstalling the tensorflow library (with an updated version) and also placed the nvcuda.dll file under system32 folder.

Answer (score 20):

This happened to me too. Most likely because the `learning_rate` was renamed from version 2.2.* to 2.3.0 in September 2018.
(see release notes: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases :
Rename lr to learning_rate for all optimizers. )

This worked for me:

```
pip install keras --upgrade
```

Answer (score 15):

Did you use a custom optimizer?

If so, you can load like this:

```
model = load_model('my_model_name.h5', custom_objects={
    'Adam': lambda **kwargs: hvd.DistributedOptimizer(keras.optimizers.Adam(**kwargs))
})
```

Alternatively you can load your model with `model = load_model('my_model_name.h5', compile=False)` and then add an optimizer and recompile, but that will lose your saved weights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I resolved it by reinstalling the tensorflow library (with an updated version) and also placed the nvcuda.dll file under system32 folder. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem loading a keras model and changing keras versions and dependencies did not work. At the end, your solution to just set compile=False worked and I did not loose any weights

Comment: @Rob model = load_model('my_model_name.h5', compile=False) helped me too !

Comment: load_model('my_model_name.h5', compile=False) helped me,U are so smart!

Answer (score 13):

In my case I found the best solution is to use h5py to change name of the variable from "learning_rate" -> "lr" as suggested in the previous posts.

```
import h5py
data_p = f.attrs['training_config']
data_p = data_p.decode().replace("learning_rate","lr").encode()
f.attrs['training_config'] = data_p
f.close()
```

Comment: This is the only working solution if you saved a model in previous version of Keras but want to load it in the new version. By the way, to open your saved model use `f = h5py.File(path_to_you_model,'r+')`

Answer (score 8):

That issue usual on dependencies difference between the kernel where that model has been trained and the dependencies versions where the model is being loaded.

If you have installed the latest version of Tensorflow now (2.1) try to load the model like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", 
       len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
# Checking the version for incompatibilities and GPU list devices 
# for a fast check on GPU drivers installation. 

model_filepath = './your_model_path.h5'

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    model_filepath,
    custom_objects=None,
    compile=False
)
```

`Compile=False` only if the model has already compiled.

Answer (score 7):

i got the same error while i was working in two different PC. 
in some versions of tensorflow is tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = x) while in other verions istf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning rate = x).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Using Keras version 2.3.1 and TensorFlow-GPU version 1.13, I had to upgrade Tensorflow-GPU to version 1.15

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Chayan Bansal, what fixed it for me was to update my Tensorflow-GPU library.

If you're using Anaconda with tensorflow-gpu installed, open the Anaconda prompt, activate the virtual environment you're using, and enter "conda update tensorflow-gpu"

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this when I try to load my model on another machine. Also trained the initial modal on an azure VM. I have tried the suggestions above and can't figure out what is causing it. Any other thoughts? Below is my code to train the model.

Models were trained and are being used in my api projects using the following versions:
keras 2.3.0
tensorflow 1.14.0

```
history = model.fit(X, y,validation_split=0.1, \
                epochs=20, \
                batch_size=1000, \
                class_weight = cw)
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a question, please post a question by clicking on a button 'Ask Question' on the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem.

You you have this issue, try to use `lr` instead of `learning_rate` when defining the learning rate in your optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same thing. You will have to upgrade to Tensorlfow 2.0 and Keras, or match the two systems together.

Answer (score 0):

Import as mentioned below,

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Comment: Where are the lines you mention?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix for me. Check your tensorflow version. 
I trained my model on 1.14 and was predicting it on 2.0

I used 1.14 again and it worked