# Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : AttributeError: module 'kerastools' has no attribute 'callback' in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Using `keras` and `tensorflow` in R and getting this error

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'kerastools' has no attribute 'callback'
```

Any idea what cause this?
PS: I looked at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028976/typeerror-unexpected-keyword-argument-passed-to-optimizer-learning-rate) but has no help on me.
The code I add is also available in [Keras intro link](https://rpubs.com/jmsallan/nn_intro)

```
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
library(dplyr)

winequality <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv", sep = ";")

red <- winequality

red <- red %>% mutate(good = ifelse(quality >= 6, 1, 0))  #factor must be encoded as numeric
red <- red %>% select(-quality)

set.seed(2020)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(red$good, p=0.8, list = FALSE)
red_train <- red %>% slice(inTrain)
red_test <- red %>% slice(-inTrain)

x_train <- red_train %>% 
  select(-good) %>% 
  scale() #we get a matrix doing this

y_train <- to_categorical(red_train$good, 2)

x_test <- red_test %>% 
  select(-good) %>% 
  scale()

y_test <- to_categorical(red_test$good, 2)

model <- keras_model_sequential() 

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = ncol(x_train)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 100, 
  batch_size = 256,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose=0
)
```

the error is in the last step

```
> model %>% fit(
+   x_train, y_train, 
+   epochs = 100, 
+   batch_size = 256,
+   validation_split = 0.2,
+   verbose=0
+ )
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'kerastools' has no attribute 'callback'
```